# Receipt Verification for Auto-Renewable Subscription in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

In my application I am using Auto-Renewable Transection. Now I have some queries in it. I have read steps for receipt verification in Apple Documentation and also refer lot's of blogs but I am not Clear about the following my scenario which I can't get.

- i.e I am subscribing for 1 month and after completion of that transection I get receipt of that transection. I am verifying it successfully. Now I need to send receipt parameter to my web service That I am sending If receipt status is '0' mean receipt is verified. Now I want to verify receipt at every time once I am starting of application that receipt is verified or not I yes the send parameter to web services and if not then send false parameter to web service.

1). Is it ok if I save receipt on completion of transection and verify that receipt at every time when app start. But will it work. Will it give me latest parameter in response. i.e if one month completed then expire date and purchase date para change so that will take effect on it.

Please suggest me the best way so That I can continues check the status of receipt and can call web services as best as I can.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Yes, OfCource it will work.. Can you explain your question clearly so that i can help you

Comment: i have saved the receipt internally and i am checking everytime when the app starts...its working properly and it is available in app store